# Security and saving files to server

Tags: php, file, security, encryption, server

I'm making a web application that is very similar to dropbox. But instead of saving files to database I save it to some folder.

For example, when user is registered, folder with it's username is created. Inside that folder all text files are saved.

Now, when creating files, user can use whatever extension they want and it will save as it. So technically speaking, someone can write php script, or even some kind of unix based that will destroy server and it will be saved in extension they want (.php, .bat, and so on...).

All I had in mind was to encrypt text and then save it to file encrypted. This way user data is secured and I hope that scripts can't be executed. I would like to hear your ideas how to make it better, and is it enough safe for me and for users.

---

Encrypted text is decrypted using javascript only when user opens it. That way, even I, with access to files can't really know whats inside it because I don't have encryption key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public and private keys.

All files uploaded on the server, regardless of type, should be encrypted via server-side encryption using the public key -- never trust the browser/user to encrypt.

Then, all files should have strict permissions set on them so that they cannot be accessed directly or even executed. CHMOD such as 600.

Lastly, on download, the contents can be decrypted with the private key by the user.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can just remove the right to execute all the files uploaded by the people with a `chmod -R -x` ?